# How to find output directory in a CSPROJ file?

Tags: c#, file-io, nuget-package, csproj

Currently I have a csproj file that gets built on an external machine.

I have multiple of the following tags in it:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="$(some_file)">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

How can I get the output directory the file is being copied to? Where in the csproj file is that defined? If not defined there, is there an API or function I can call from a .cs script to get the output directory for a specific project? Moreover, aside from the output directory, how can I get the specific output path for such a file in the  tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/message-task?view=vs-2022)  task to output the output directory.  In general its based off of the directory the project is in, but it can be redefined at any point in the CS proj or any included msbuild file.  All Vars in MS build can also be set by Env Vars so you would need to add the message task to be sure.  You can also up your build verbosity and see the value of all the variables.